# syntaxique.tab.c: undefined reference to yylex

Tags: bison, yacc

I am trying to run an example  But I have this error showing every time I run my gcc command. Here are the commands that I run:

```
flex lexical.l
bison -d syntaxique.y
 gcc -o lex.yy.c syntaxique.tab.c
```

-> at this point I got this error message:

> syntaxique.tab.c:(.text+0x1ee): undefined reference to `yylex'

Here is my code:

lexical.l:

```
%{
    #include"stdio.h"
int nbr_ligne;
#include "syntaxique.tab.h"

extern YYSTYPE yylval;

%}
chiffre [0-9]
cst [1-9][0-9]*|0
vide [ \t]+
saut_ligne [\n]
idf [A-Z]([_]?[a-z0-9])*
int ([1-9][0-9]*|0)
float ([1-9][0-9]*|0)","([0-9]*[1-9])
bool       "FALSE"|"TRUE" 
varint        "INT"|"int"
varfloat      "FLOAT"|"float"
varbool       "BOOL"|"bool"
 const_int "const int"|"CONST INT"
const_float "const float"|"CONST FLOAT"
op "*"|"+"|"-"|"/"|"%"
rat "<"|"<="|"<>"|"=="|">"|">="|"!="
incr "++"
decr "--"
arc "("
farc ")"
aff "=" 
vg ","
pvg ";"
debut "{"
fin "}"
 if "if"|"IF"|"If"
for "for"|"FOR"
begin "begin"|"BEGIN"
end "end"|"END"
comment       "//" (.|\n)* "//"


%%
{idf}         {printf(" idf");if (yyleng <= 12 ){yylval.str=strdup(yytext);return(mc_idf);} }
{const_float} {printf(" const_float");return const_float;}
{const_int}   {printf(" const_int");return const_int;}
{vide}
{begin}     {return(mc_begin);}
{end}           {return(mc_end);}
{varint}        { yylval.type=strdup(yytext);return(mc_varint);}
{varfloat}      { yylval.type=strdup(yytext); return(mc_float);}
{varbool}       {yylval.type=strdup(yytext);return(mc_varbool);}
{int}           {yylval.entier=atoi(yytext);return(mc_int);}
{float}         {yylval.entier=atof(yytext);return(mc_float);}
{bool}          {yylval.type=strdup(yytext);return(mc_bool);}       
{if}              {return(mc_if);}
{for}             {return(mc_for);}
{rat} {return mc_rat;}
{op} {return mc_op;}

 {pvg} {printf(" pvg");return pvg;}
 {vg} {printf(" vg");return vg;}
{arc} {printf(" arc");return arc;}
{farc} {printf(" farc");return farc;}
 {debut} {printf(" debut");return debut;}
{fin} {printf(" fin");return fin;}
{incr} {printf(" incr");return incr;}
{decr} {printf(" decr");return decr;}
 {aff} {printf(" aff");return aff;}



 [\n] {nbr_ligne++;} 

.+ {printf("erreur");}


%%
int yywrap(){
return 1;}

int main(){
yylex();
return 0;
}
```

here is syntaxique.y:

```
    %{
    #include "stdio.h"

#include "string.h"


int yyerror(char *s);

int yylex();

int yyerror(char *s);

int nb_ligne = 1;

float test;

char suavType [20];

char value [100] ;


%}

 %union{ 

int entier; 

float reel; 

char* str; 

char oper; 

char* type;

char* idf;

char symbol;

char* bool;}

// LISTE of terminal

%token  var <entier>mc_int <reel>mc_float<oper>mc_div

<bool>mc_bool <type>mc_varbool <idf>mc_idf <const>mc_const <type>mc_varint <type>mc_varfloat 
mc_begin

mc_for mc_if mc_end mc_rat <oper>mc_op <symbol>pvg <symbol>vg <symbol>aff debut fin arc farc incr 
decr

const_int const_float



%start S


%%


S:Declaration mc_begin LIST_INST mc_end {printf("programme correcte syntaxiquement ");YYACCEPT;}

;

TYPEVAR: mc_varfloat {strcpy(suavType,$1)} | mc_varint {strcpy(suavType,$1)} | mc_varbool 

{strcpy(suavType,$1)}

;

 // LE CAS D'UNE DÉCLARATION DE PLUSIEURS VARIABLES: int a,b...

VG: vg Idf VG |

;

// LE CAS D'UNE DÉCLARATION DE PLUSIEURS CONSTANTE: const int a=6,b=6...

VGCONST : vg Idf aff CONST VG|

;

Idf: mc_idf

;

 IDFConst: const_int  mc_idf | const_float mc_idf

;

Declaration:

      Declaration TYPEVAR Idf VG pvg |

     Declaration IDFConst aff CONST VGCONST pvg  |

 ;

// LISTE DES CONSTANTES

CONST: mc_float{ test=$1; strcpy(value,"FLOAT");}|mc_int{ 

test=$1;strcpy(value,"INT");}|mc_bool{strcpy(value,"BOOL");}|mc_idf|

;

// OPÉRATION ARITHMÉTIQUE

EXPARITH:CONST mc_op EXPARITH | CONST |arc EXPARITH farc|

CONST mc_op mc_idf EXPARITH | mc_idf mc_op CONST EXPARITH

AFFECOND:mc_idf aff EXPARITH 

;

LIST_INST:  AFFECOND LIST_INST | InstIF LIST_INST | InstFOR LIST_INST |

; 

InstIF: mc_if arc CONDITION farc debut LIST_INST fin 

;

InstFOR: mc_for arc AFFECOND vg CONDITION vg Compteur farc debut LIST_INST fin 

;

CONDITION:CONST mc_rat CONST | mc_bool | EXPARITH mc_rat EXPARITH

;

Compteur: mc_idf incr| mc_idf decr


;

%%

int yyerror(char *msg) {

printf("ERREUR syntaxique a la ligne %d" ,nb_ligne);

return 0;

}







int main () { 

yyparse();

return 0; }
```

please help me to compile it

Comment: Flex rules must start exactly at the left margin. Any indented line is considered source code to be inserted in the generated code, which will usually create compiler errors. It's possible that you just pasted the code badly; it's important that you paste code correctly to avoid misleading people trying to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're telling gcc to compile and link syntaxique.tab.c and save the resulting executable as lex.yy.c. You're not compiling or linking the contents of lex.yy.c.

You should either remove the `-o` or provide an actual name for the executable.

Comment: when i remove  -o i have this problem:     multiple definition of `main';  do you have an idea ??

Comment: @yacineR You've defined a `main` function in both of your files. You can't define two functions with the same name in a C program (unless they're static, but they're not and you can't define a static main function anyway).

Comment: i generate the executable file but when i write:     int a=2; it generate an 'error' but i'm pretty sure that my syntaxique file is correct .any idea why??

Comment: @yacineR At a glance, it does not look like `int a = 2;` would match your `S` rule, which seems to require `begin` and `end` keywords.

Comment: i have already the same problem when i write:   { int a; begin a=2; end}